# Unity - Navigation for performance on mobile

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

In case of a Unity mobile app, would it be good (at all) for performance, to deactivate the navigation through canvas objects like TextFields and Buttons?

When selecting e.g. a Button or TextField in the sceneview, the inspector shows the option "Navigation", which can be set to different things and can also be visualized. This feature is usually used to tab through input fields, like you would expect it on a website. On my mobile game I don't need this "tabbing". Would there be any sort of performance increase if I deactivated it everywhere?

Comment: Destroy and Instantiate is good for freeing memory, but only if you don't use it frequently.

If you believe a certain button will be rarely rendered, you may opt for destroying it.

Comment: Tavados - It is utterly irrelevant.  Forget about it.  If the buttons are not in use, just hide them.  There's nothing more to it.

Comment: This is not about hiding or showing the buttons. My post has been edited heavily and basically changed the topic, so I edited it back and explain a bit more what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm, that deactivating the navigation of UI elements has no performance influence. Behind the scenes there's just a handler, that gets triggered, when you hit "tab" on pc, or analogeously on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

> Would deactivating this rather be a waste of time, or even make
>   performance worse for some obscure reason?

Usually there are 3 ways to show and hide UI. I will list them from worst to best.

**1**.Instantiate (Show), Destroy (Hide).

```
public GameObject uiPanelPrefab;

void Start()
{
    //Show
    Instantiate(uiPanelPrefab);
    //Hide
    Destroy(uiPanelPrefab);
}
```

*This creates and destroys Objects each time. (Not Recommended).*

**2**.Activate (Show) or Deactivate (Hide) the GameObject of that UI.

```
public GameObject uiPanelPrefab;

void Start()
{
    //Show
    uiPanelPrefab.SetActive(true);
    //Hide
    uiPanelPrefab.SetActive(false);
}
```

*This creates garbage each time it is set to active and also cause quick freezes. You will notice this a lot when making VR apps. Fine on Desktops. Not good or recommended on mobile devices.*

**3**.Enable (Show) or Disable (Hide) the `Component` of that UI.

```
public GameObject uiPanelPrefab;

void Start()
{
    //Show
    uiPanelPrefab.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
    //Hide
    uiPanelPrefab.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
}
```

This simply enables and disables the components. This method requires a custom function for each UI Control such as `Button`, `Text`, `InputField` as each Control has different components attached to them. This is the recommended method especially on mobile devices.

---

After long experiment with these, I came to conclusion that **#3** is the best and should be used.The downside is that you have to make a function that will disable every components of each UI Control.

For example, the `Button` Control has more than 1 components. Simply disabling the `Button` component will not do it. You have to write a simple function that will disable `Button`, `Image` and `Text` components. Something like below:

```
void showButton(GameObject button, bool show, bool includeInactive = false)
{
    Button bt = button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(includeInactive);
    bt.enabled = show;

    Text txt = button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(includeInactive);
    txt.enabled = show;

    Image img = button.GetComponentInChildren<Image>(includeInactive);
    img.enabled = show;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
//Show
showButton(uiPanelPrefab, true);

//Hide
showButton(uiPanelPrefab, false);
```

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: This is completely off topic. You edited the title and the content of my post and then wrote an answer that doesn't match my initial question at all.

Comment: I rolled it back to your original question. Your question is about if it better to deactivate UI components like textfields and buttons... This is your question. I provided ways to do that then told you that it is better to enable/disable the component instead of deactivating them.

Comment: I renamed the title and added more details because you got a downvote and they early closed the question. What in my answer is off topic?

Comment: Now you have overwritten my question again! You seemingly don't get what I am writing about (ok, maybe it was bad formulated the first time) and so you answer doesn't fit at all. Please stop changing my question.